# How to create weekly leaderboard with Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I would like to create a leaderboard, which will display how many times user started the app. There should be all-time and weekly leaderboards. Let's say I count number of apps start locally and with each change submit incremented number:

```
Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(), LEADERBOARD_ID, 10);
```

But it will work for one week only - let's say user run the app for 10 times on week 1. Next week, once app is started, I will have to submit 11. It is OK for all-time leaderboard, but will not work for weekly leaderboard.

What should I do to achieve what I want?

The only idea I have is to have two different leaderboards:

```
Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(), WEEKLY_LEADERBOARD_ID, 1);
Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(), ALLTIME_LEADERBOARD_ID, 11);
```

But would it be possible to show weekly results **only** in WEEKLY_LEADERBOARD_ID and all-time results in ALLTIME_LEADERBOARD_ID? Would it be user friendly? Or, is there any other better option?

Answer (score 1):

Two of the methods in the Leaderboards reference have a span parameter with the accepted values **TIME_SPAN_DAILY**, **TIME_SPAN_WEEKLY**, or **TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME**. Mainly the functions **loadTopScores** and **loadPlayerCenteredScores** should be useful to you. You can find the full documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboards.html). It seems like you need to use  two leaderboards because the scores are inherently different and load the scores based on your weekly/all time use cases.